# nameof equivalent for multiple levels

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a `.cshtml` page I would like to avoid writing strings so I can get compiler support for misspellings. What I am after is the equivalent of `nameof` but different. For example,

```
nameof(Three.Four.Five) // returns Five
```

but I would like "Three.Four.Five" to be returned. I already have the following:

```
public static string FullHtmlFieldNameFor<T, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<T> html, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
{
    return html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
}
```

that I use but that is different because I use it like this:

```
<label>@Html.FullHtmlFieldNameFor(x=> x.One.Two.Three.Four.Five)</label>
```

As you can see, the above will return "One.Two.Three.Four.Five" but I would like the name to be "Three.Four.Five". I was thinking of adding another parameter to the above to specify how many levels to return from the expression. For example, 3, would return "Three.Four.Five" but using it would be like this:

```
<label>@Html.FullHtmlFieldNameFor(x=> x.One.Two.Three.Four.Five, 3)</label>
```

but I don't like that because when you are reading the code you still see "One.Two.Three.Four.Five" and it seems the label is for "One.Two.Three.Four.Five".

**Question**

How can I pass `Three.Four.Five` or an expression such as `x => x.Three.Four.Five` in the above scenario?

**Edit**

I even created this method:

```
public static string GetFieldName<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
{
    return ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
}
```

but the usage is too busy: `GetFieldName<Two, int>(x => x.Three.Four.Five)`

Comment: the last solution you've presented looks good. are you saying you want to pass `x.Three.Four.Five` instead of `x.One.Two.Three.Four.Five`?

Comment: @RufusL Yes exactly. Please see my edit.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the generic types to `GetFieldName`? C# should be able to infer them from the argument for you. Alternatively, change the lambda you pass to `FullHtmlFieldNameFor` by typing `x`. BTW, I don't see a method named `FullHtmlFieldNameFor` in .Net?

Comment: @NetMage C# cannot infer them from the argument in this case. Try it out. `FullHtmlFieldNameFor` is my own method that I have shown in my questions.

Comment: You need to specify the type of `Two` as the lambda parameter: e.g. `(cTwo x) => x.Three.Four.Five)`...

Answer (score 0):

What if you create a helper that takes two parameters?

```
public static string FullHtmlFieldNameFromFor<TBase, T, TResult>(this TBase obj, Func<TBase, T> _, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression) => ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
```

Then you can use:

```
<label>@Html.FullHtmlFieldNameFromFor(x => x.One.Two, x => x.Three.Four.Five)</label>
```

Alternatively, what if you create multiple helpers for each subclass you may want to use as a name basis?

```
public static string GetFieldName(Expression<Func<cTwo, object>> expression) => ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
public static string GetFieldName(Expression<Func<cThree, object>> expression) => ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
```

Then you can use each one.